# Run rails console on application deployed to EC2 with rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubber

I am attempting to debug my rails application which is currently deployed to EC2 with the Rubber gem.

I've attempted to ssh in to my instance, but it does not seem to take me to the directory of a rails project.  Thus, I am unable to run rail console and debug my application.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Do you know which directory your application has been placed in? Check the `/var/www/` directory also if you are not sure about it.

Comment: I just solved the issue.  Rubber installs your application within the apache2 directory.  I just cd'd into my application and ran 'bundle exec rails c.' Thanks for your help